# Odoo 10 report: Print variable just at the end of page

Tags: qweb

```
<t t-if="page_index &lt; page_size - 1">
    <tr class="text-right">
        <td colspan="6">
            <strong>Subtotal: </strong>
               <t t-set="subtotal_total" t-value="subtotal_total+l.price_subtotal"/>
               <span t-esc="subtotal_total" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary',
                'display_currency': doc.pricelist_id.currency_id}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</t>
```

I'm trying to print just at the end of the page this variable "subtotal_total". If I remove main t tag, acumulative value appears each line in loop, but I just want to print at the end of page.

I have printed page_index and page_size and I'm always getting 0 and 1 constant values respectively.